# executeQuery command is not working

Tags: hsqldb, ms-access-2013, netbeans-8

executeQuery command is not working when fetching data from ms access in java 8 using hsql. While db is connected.

Don't know where I'm mistaking.?

```
String sql="select * from ADMIN";
```

rs=st.executeQuery(sql);

Comment: Any one here.? Please help.!!

Comment: Please add more details. You mention both MS Access and HSQLDB, which are different databases.

Comment: I'm trying to connect to the ms access through java8, but as i researched java8 doesn't support ODBC driver. It supports HSQL.

So, I download all the required jar files and imported them to the project and my program is connected to access DB, But the issue is, it doesn't executed SQL query.?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ucanaccess

Comment: Thank you. Issue has been resolved.!!